# Searching a way to insert a data to excel template and save it with python

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

After search attempts I'm trying to ask here.

I handle data inside JSON file and after manipulation as a dictionary (json load), I'm converting it to DataFrame (using pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) and then I'm trying to save it to excel file with pandas (to_excel).

I'm trying to find a way to load an xlsx file **with all the design** (kind of template), and then to save the xlsx with new data inserted to the right positions and save on the designing.
Where should I look for it?

Thank you :)

Comment: Start by looking at [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you.
I'm read the documentation and I find the add_table() function and it's looking good.
but what if I want to import an existing file, with all the designing? How do I keep on these properties (like header color, styles etc...)?